# Importing of js files which have been created from TypeScript files

Tags: typescript

There are two typescript files which are modules and one of them is used as external module.As far as I understood using external modules is more comfortable than internal ones because you don't have to type a namespace before a class everytime.
I have a task namely :

```
Create modular typescript files -> Compile them into js files -> 
-> import the js files into a html page
```

The problem is - the browser can't find the exports of js files but when I am trying it on the node js compiler it's totally working.

```
main.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at main.js:2
(anonymous) @ main.js:2
person.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at person.js:2
```

The project structure is :

```
Project
      -> main.html
      -> typescriptsources
                          -> main.ts
                          -> person.ts
```

The ts files source is given below :

```
 // main.ts
 import {Person} from './person';
 var person : Person = new Person("Sergey" , "Sckoriy");
 console.log(person.greet());


// person.ts
export class Person {
    name : string;
    surname : string;
    constructor (name : string , surname : string){
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    greet():string {
        var text:string = "Hello" + this.name;
        return text;
    }
}

//main.html
<html>...
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "typescriptsources/main.js">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "typescriptsources/person.js">
```

Now , it's being compiled with

```
tsc --module commonjs main.js
```

The result of compilation is :

```
// main.js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var person_1 = require("./person");
var person = new person_1.Person("Sergey", "Sckoriy");
console.log(person.greet());   

// person.js

"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var Person = /** @class */ (function () {
function Person(name, surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}
Person.prototype.greet = function () {
    var text = "Hello" + this.name;
    return text;
};
return Person;
}());
exports.Person = Person;
```

Comment: "On the web, you can tell browsers to treat a `<script>` element as a module by setting the `type` attribute to module." (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules)
Have you tried that?